# Python: Skipping lines from file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a data file that has 100 lines and I want create a dictionary that skips the first two lines and then create a dictionary with enumerating keys with the lines as values.

```
myfile = open(infile, 'r')
d={}
with myfile as f:
    next(f)
    next(f)
    for line in f:
```

This is what I got, I don't how to use iteritems(), enumerate(), or itervalues() but I feel like I think I will use them or maybe not if anybody can help me.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do something like:

```
from itertools import islice
with open(infile, 'r') as myfile:
  d = dict(enumerate(islice(myfile, 2, None)))
```

But I wish I understood why you want to skip the first two lines – are you sure you don't want `linecache`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just going to be of the top of my head so the will certainly be room for improvement.

---

```
myfile = open(infile, 'r') # open the file
d = {}                     # initiate the dict

for line in myfile:        # iterate over lines in the file
  counter = 0              # initiate the counter
  if counter <= 1:         # if we have counted under 2 iterations
    counter += 1           # increase the counter by 1 and do nothing else
  else:                    # if we have counted over 2 iterations
    d[counter - 2] = line  # make a new key with the name of lines counted (taking in to consideration the 2 lines precounted)
    counter += 1           # increase the counter by 1 before continuing
```

---

I can not of the top of my head remember where in the code it would be best to close the file but do some experimentation and read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). And another time a good place to start would really be [google](http://www.google.com/) and the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/contents.html) in general.

Comment: It's probably better to use a `with` statement rather than explicitly closing the file – the `with` block will take care of closing the file even if there's an error.